# sort NSFetchedResultsController on IBAction

Tags: uitableview, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

i want to sort my Data in my Tableview. I have UIButtons with IBAction to call the sort.
I have created a string which contains the sortKey. I am setting the the key and call the fetchedResultsController again, to sort the tableview.

Problem is, fetchedResultsController method is not called and the sorting doesnt work.
 here is my code:

```
- (IBAction) actionSortCardColor:(id) sender {
    XLog(@"");
    sortString = @"colorOrder";
    [self fetchedResultsController];

    [self actionRemoveSortView:sender];
}
```

Here my fetchedResultsController method:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{

[...]


NSPredicate *inboxPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"archived == 0"];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:inboxPred];

XLog(@"sortString: %@", sortString);
if (sortString == nil) {
    sortString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sortingOrder"];
}

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"setTitle" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortString ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor2, nil] autorelease];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[...]
}
```

Comment: so, you mean, you already have fetched results, but they are not sorted. Once user taps on the button, they should get sorted, and the tableView should display the same result, but in a sorted fashion. Right?

Comment: Exactly. What i have done is, in IBACtion i set the __fetchedResultsController ivar to nil, so the sort is working(fetchedResultsController method gets entered), but that is not the right way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is it that you let the table view know about these changes? You'll need to reload the data for your table view instance `[tableView reloadData];`

When you set the __fetchedResultsController to nil, it cannot update the UITable view with any changes because it isn't in scope.